# How to use GDAL's ogr2ogr to create bounding box

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr

I'm learning about GeoJSON and following [Bostock's Lets Make a Map tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/). Here he uses Natural Earth data, and converts SHP files to JSON for use in D3. The following takes only GBR and IRL data from the SHP file to create subunits.json, which I load into D3 to draw my map.

```
> ogr2ogr \
  -f GeoJSON \
  -where "ADM0_A3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')" \
  subunits.json \
  ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
```

> ogr2ogr has many more powerful
>   features...The -clipdst argument, for
>   example, clips the shapefile to a rectangular bounding box, useful for
>   displaying only a small part of certain features.

I'd like to create a bounding box for displaying only a small area such as the area around Birmingham. How do I calculate the xmin ymin etc for this? This is the usage [[-clipdst [xmin ymin xmax ymax]|WKT|datasource]](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) but what exactly should it look like?

Comment: You need to determine the coordinates of the corner points of the bounding box by e.g. inspecting the data in a GIS program.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I think I can use Google Earth Pro for this. I'm not really clear on how to structure it, would I write something like -clipdst [-76.13 76.58 -71.50 79.60 |WKT| ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp ?

Comment: You just give it a list of numbers: `-clipdst 1 2 3 4`.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I was clearly over thinking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example of the `clipdst` syntax at the bottom of the page you shared:

> Example reprojecting from ETRS_1989_LAEA_52N_10E to EPSG:4326 and clipping to a bounding box

```
ogr2ogr -wrapdateline -t_srs EPSG:4326 -clipdst -5 40 15 55 france_4326.shp europe_laea.shp
```

http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html#ogr2ogr_example